# AJAX create form/table on change

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic

I have a table that is populated from a Database. How would I go about only having this table populate once the user changes a selectbox option? I think I need to us AJAX and onchange for the dropdown as the query for the table will alter pending the dropdown selection, though im not sure how to go about this. I know it can't be too hard, but I need to see an example before I can understand it and apply elsewhere.

Using php 5.2

I tried following the W3 examples but they did not seem to cover this area. More of loading an existing file to present text. I wasn't sure how to apply that to this.

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
   <select name="caseless_numbers" id="ValTwo" class="DropChange">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="1">A</option>
       <option value="2">B</option>
       <option value="3">C</option>
       <option value="4">D</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Search for AJAX and how that works.

Comment: Are you alright with using jQuery? [Here is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843) that links to several simple examples to get started on AJAX. One of them involves using SELECT controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

Wrap the table in a div called `tablewrap` or whatever and then 
add a change event to the dropdown. Using a jQuery post you can then send the value as a variable called `selection` to a php script to make the table and then use the result as the html for the div:

```
$("#ValTwo").on("change", function() {
    $.post("getTableData.php", { selection: $(this).val()  },   function(data) {    
    $("#tablewrap").html(data.table);   
    }, "json");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to read up on [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [how to use them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest).

There are literally dozens of articles online that discuss in great detail how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you are using as a server side language, I cannot give you an example of that.  Here is an example of an ajax post that uses ASP.NET MVC4 server side.

**jQuery:**

```
$('#ValTwo').change(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/{controller}/{action}/",
    data: { 'Selection' : $('#ValTwo').val() }, //PASSES BACK SELECT VALUE
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, text) {
      //APPEND TABLE HERE, 'data' WILL CONTAIN ANYTHING RETURNED
  });
});
```

**NOTE:** Any input/select/textarea controls added to the page after it load *(ie: in the success method)* will need to use `$.live` to add any event listeners.

**jQuery Documentation on Ajax:** http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Sorry I should have said Linux, php 5.2. Though im sure I can break your example down

Comment: The only real difference here is the url property wouldn't be correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is much to be said for building your own AJAX mechanism to do this -- as an academic exercise.  If, however, you want a robust solution with maximum cross-browser compatibility and a robust feature set, I would recommend looking at the combination of jQuery and [datatables](https://datatables.net/).  A lot of datatable's functionality will be obscure without a secure grounding in how AJAX works, but I have found this combination to be an enormous saver of time and energy in production environments.

Using this route, you'd want to look closely at the [Server Side Processing](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) examples.  It is important to note that you can use either a script URL or a callback function for this option property, and that you can force a datatable to pull freshly from the server in an on-change event (look at the [fnReloadAjax plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api)).

There is some room for confusion in mastering these tools, but they are very powerful and will earn their keep in the long run.