# $.get() method JQuery reads nothing (html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Goal:**

When **click_div** is clicked, the script should read a file (**text.html**) from my own computer using **$.get() method**, and set the html of a div (**cont_div**) to the file's content.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click_div').click(function(){
        var HTML_FILE_URL = 'text.html';
        $.get(HTML_FILE_URL, function(data){
            alert(data);
            $('#cont_div').html(text);
        });
    });
});
```

**Problem:**

The content of **cont_div** keeps blank, after clicking **click_div**. I put an alert to show the content of what the get method read, and it displays a blank dialog.

**Further information:**

• The file is on the same folder as the .js file, and the **index.html** page file.

• All the other javascript functions work well.

**Question:**

Given that the alert function displays nothing, but is still called, what could I possibly be doing wrong? I've tried many things, but it really doesn't work.

Comment: Are both files in same directory? any console errors?

Comment: You need to be running a server on your system to use get.

Comment: @JeffPowers Only if you're using google chrome without removing the security settings

Comment: Are you sure your `text.html` html document actually contains anything? if you're getting to success but no data is in the alert, that suggests that it is found but is empty.

Comment: Also, is that a typo? `.html(text)` vs `.alert(data)`

Comment: In the off-chance that naomik is not correct and you really are trying to do AJAX, [here are some examples to review](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)

Comment: Are you running this through a web browser or just loading the file into your browser straight from the file system? You may get permission problems if trying to do the latter.

Comment: @Chris yeah, that might be the problem. Let me try using __load__, as naomik suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are appending the wrong variable

`$('#cont_div').html(text);`

should likely be

`$('#cont_div').html(data);`

Also, I would look into `$.load()`. I think it would be a bit simpler for your case.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click_div').click(function(){
        var HTML_FILE_URL = 'text.html';
         $('#cont_div').load(HTML_FILE_URL);
    });
});
```

should work.