# Populating a div that was generated in an earlier ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a few problems with jQuery/AJAX and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction!

I have an AJAX request on my page that populates a div (call it with div 1) with a select box. Also contained is another DIV (call it div 2). After selecting an option from the select box and clicking a button, I then want to populate div 2 with some extra information. However, when I try to do this, it appears that jQuery is trying to load div 1 with the new information. When I use chrome to inspect the element, I can see that when the button is clicked that div 2 is removed for some reason. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Nice description of the problem, could you post the code along with it? :D

Comment: @user2748228 Is this question still open? If not, please close the question (by choosing a best answer) and upvoting any answers that were helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible to answer this question without seeing your code, but here is another SO question that discusses how to populate `<select>` control B, based on the contents of `<select>` control A.

[Three Ajax examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843) (look at the last one)