# Continuously submitting a form, purposefully?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, http, post

I'm trying to automate a process.

I have a form when submitted makes a $.post() request to a PHP file and returns the result to the page.

I wanted to know how I could have it send X amount of POST requests depending on what the user sets the amount of requests to and with customized settings to change the settings of the request depending on the last result.

How would this be possible using jQuery/JS/PHP?

Example: http://puu.sh/4kipZ.jpg

You can choose the amount of requests you want and customize parameters (On win, On Loss).

Thanks.

Comment: Well , you can make your AJAX call inside a loop which runs to the length of the amount of requests set by the user.

Comment: How would that be done exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `constant in PHP` for the amount of times the request is to be made. Then u`se it in JQuery`

In PHP

```
define('REQUEST_AMOUNT', X);
```

IN HTML

```
<input type='hidden' id='amount', val='<?PHP echo REQUEST_AMOUNT;?>'>
```

IN JQUERY

```
var amount = $('#amount').val();
```

Now `amount` is the number of times you have to make request

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @JohnSmith that's as basic as it gets. Do your work yourself.

Comment: @schlingel that doesn't make any sense.  Look at the example.  How would it submit hundreds of requests repeatedly to that file and change the parameters..?

Comment: @JohnSmith It does. You are asking a very basic question again.

Comment: That doesn't really explain much.   Could you give an example based on the example picture I posted..?

Comment: The picture doesn't explain much. Rephrase your problem and what you tried, or pay me 80$ per hour and I do your work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea how to do it.  As you can see, AJAX is the key.

Note that `$.post()` is almost identical to using `$.ajax()` -- but `$.post()` has a few settings hard-coded. The structure that I used is usually easiest when starting out, and then move on to the other formats, promise-based, etc.

Sorry, cannot do a jsFiddle for this because AJAX won't work over jsFiddle. However, this answer is completely stand-alone. Just copy/paste it into two files and run:

**index.php** (or whatever you wish to name it)
**your_php_processor.php** (if rename file, must also rename it in the ajax code block)

---

**HTML and Javascript/jQuery:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var numrolls, ta;
                $('#txtArea').attr({'disabled':'disabled'});

                $('#gobutt').click(function() {
                    numrolls = $('#rollnum').val();
                    $('#txtArea').html('Results of ' +numrolls+ ' automated rolls:\r\n\r\n');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "your_php_processor.php",
                        data: 'rolls=' + numrolls,
                        success:function(data){
                            ta = $('#txtArea').val() + '\r\n';
                            $('#txtArea').val(ta + data);
                        }
                    });

                });


            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    Number of rolls to automate:<br>
    <input type="text" id="rollnum" /><input type="button" id="gobutt" value="Go!" /><br>
    <br>
    Results:<br>
    <textarea id="txtArea" rows="20" cols="30" ></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

**your_php_processor.php**

```
<?php

$rr = $_POST['rolls'];

$all = '';

for ($i=1; $i<=$rr; $i++) {
    $rand = mt_rand(1, 6);
    $all .= $rand . "\r\n";
}

echo $all;
```

---

For more info/examples re AJAX, see the [simple examples in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)

You may also find [the comments following this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-random-number-generator/) to be of interest as they discuss the legality of using various built-in random number generators.