# How do you produce a dialog box on hover over checkbox via jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

Since I don't know much about jQuery I have am not being able to produce a dialog box on hover over a checkbox. Any suggestion would be helpful. Below is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="employee-id" name="employeeId" onmouseover="produceDialog()">
<div id="employee-info-div"></div>
```

Similarly my jQuery is:

```
produceDialog(){
     $("employee-info-div").dialog({
        open : function ( event, ui ) {

            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        },
        dialogClass : 'fixed-dialog',
        resizable : false,
        height : 150,
        width : 250,
        modal : false,
        create : function ( event ) {

            $(event.target).parent().css('position', 'fixed');
        },
      
    });
```

}

Answer (score 5):

This may be the example you are looking for:

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d6rhc/)

Below is a stand-alone example, which should just be copy/play.

Notes:

The element `$('#employee-info-div');` was assigned to a variable to make code more efficient *and* faster to type. (More efficient b/c only check DOM once for the element, retrieve from variable after that.)

Used jQuery `hover()` method to open the dialog, but initialized the dialog separately (upon document ready). Note that the hover method *must* have two functions associated with it; the second function need not do anything but it must be there.

The hover-IN method assigned to the class `$('.employee-id')` runs the code `$('#employee-info-div').dialog('open');`, which opens the dialog. Note that the 2nd element is accessed via variable name.

Copy/Paste the following code into a separate document in your webroot and run, OR just use the above jsFiddle link to see it all in action.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <style>
            #employee-info-div{
                width:40%; 
                float:right; 
                padding:5px; 
                background:wheat; 
                color:blue;
            }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var eid = $('#employee-info-div');
                var blurb = '<h2>Employee Information:</h2>Here is some example information about this employee. It can be text inserted like this, or it can be information retrieved from a database via AJAX. For simple AJAX examples, <a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843"> see this StackOverflow post </a> (remember to upvote any posts that are helpful to you, please.)';

                function hovIn() {
                    $(this).css({'font-weight':'bold','color':'blue'});
                    eid.html(blurb);
                    eid.dialog('open');
                }
                function hovOut() {
                    //eid.html(''); //<-- Causes dlg text to appear/disappear as you move mouse on/off checkbox and label
                    $(this).css({'font-weight':'normal','color':'black'});
                }

                $('.employee-id').hover(hovIn, hovOut);

                eid.dialog({
                    autoOpen:false,
                    title:"Your jQueryUI Dialog",
                    show: "fade",
                    hide: "fade",
                    width:500, //orig defaults: width: 300, height: auto
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function() {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                }); //END eid.dialog

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    Hover over below checkbox to see hidden DIV:<br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="employee-id" class="employee-id" name="employeeId" ><span class="employee-id">Hover over this checkbox</span>
    <div id="employee-info-div"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the hover event to your checkbox:

```
$("#employee-id").hover(function(){
    // call your produceDialog function here
});
```

Comment: it works. You should add function before produceDialog. Also, you missed the '#' here: $("employee-info-div"). Here's a fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/Bg2jD/

Comment: Hey yeah thanks it works for normal checkboxes but i have various properties added to teh checkbox from javascript perhaps that's teh reason why its not working.Anyways thanks:)