# How to dynamically add List items in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an mobile app in which i want to populate ListView once the user fill up the form and click on submit button.

I know how to give List View in jQuery but how to populate items in it dynamically at run time?

Comment: Checkout http://handlebarsjs.com/, literally doing this exact thing in one of my projects right now.

Comment: I am new to this so i just went through the http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/  but don't have any idea how to proceed. please do provide some tips

Comment: I second using handlebarsjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo:**](http://jsfiddle.net/7PzcN/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id="listView"></div>
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Submit" />
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    var out = '<ul><li>Item One</li><li>Item Two</li><li>Item Three</li></ul>';
    $('#listView').html(out);
});
```

---

Responding to your comment: *"what i need is on click of button form gets submitted and firstname which user enters on form will get added in list"*

First, you need to remain on the page after the form was submitted.  To do that, you should add `e.preventDefault();` in your submit routine:

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
    //Manually collect form values and 
    //Use ajax to submit form values here (see notes at bottom)
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Next, you want to get the data that was in the desired field, and add that to the `<ul>`. Therefore, change the above like this:

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var fn = $('#fname').val();
    $('ul').append('<li>' +fn+ '</li>');

    //Manually collect form values and 
    //Use ajax to submit form values here (see notes at bottom)
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

For the AJAX bit, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843) for tips.

Note that you can use `$('#formID').serialize();` to quickly serialize all form data.

Comment: in above example it is hard coded items but what i need is on click of button form gets submitted and firstname which user enters on form will get added in list.

Answer (score 1):

**js fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/7PzcN/1/**

**html:**

```
<div id="listView"></div>
<input type="text" name="firstname"/>
<input type="text" name="lastname"/>
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Submit" />
```

**jquery:**

```
$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    var out = '<ul>';
    $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
        out += "<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>";
    });
    out += "</ul>";
    $('#listView').html(out);
});
```