# PHP mail function always returning false

Tags: php, email

I want to send mails using php from my website. I have done the following steps but still the mail is not working. It is always returning a false.

I have created a mail id and then has changed SMTP, smtp_port and sendmail_from values in php.ini file. I have tested setting the SMTP and smtp to both default values(localhost and 25) and the values given in mail client config of cpanel (abc-22.example.net and 465). I have also checked phpinfo to check whether those values were set successfully. I have checked the error log also, no errors logged there. The php version installed on server is 5.4.24.

Comment: Have you tried using a library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)?

Comment: have you restart your apache server or wamp server?

Comment: Did you connect to your mail-server with `telnet` or similar to verify it is actually working and receiving mail?

Comment: No, I am going to check it out...

Comment: @grebneke I checked it already. Its working with the webmail perfectly .

Comment: Do you have access to your mailserver logs, check there?

Comment: @grebneke I can't find the mailserver log. I can't access /usr directory, error logs are usually there right.

Comment: @Bishal: If you have ssh-access and can run PHP from the commandline, a last resort could be to use `strace` to run your script and see exactly what it sends to the mailserver and the response it gets. It's an advanced command so you need to read up on `strace` to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use SMTP Authentication for mail sending by using phpmailer. mail() is not allowed on some hosting side. Because of spaming.

Click [here](http://www.mendoweb.be/blog/php-send-mail-smtp-server-authentication-required/)!

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the `From:` attribute in the header?

Some ISPs will block your mail if you do that.

[See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322838/php-form-will-not-do-the-last-step/21323416#21323416)