# How to send contenteditable value in td with php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html, contenteditable

I have the following code in my page:

```
 echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #FFA500;' contenteditable='true'>".$result['body']."</td>";
```

And I want to send the edited content to mysql_query.

do I simply have to add id to `<td>` and use ajax??

Comment: var theContent = getElementbyID('edited');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Please check the following question for more information, references and helpful answers:
[How to save and retrieve contenteditable data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790268/how-to-save-and-retrieve-contenteditable-data)

---

Yes, you have to use AJAX to store the edited content, or use a script that generates (*hidden*) input fields and submits a form with the edited values.

Ready more about **contenteditable** here (particularly 'Storing the changes'):
http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/#storing-changes

It gives you a [JS Bin code snippet](http://jsbin.com/owavu3/1/edit?html,css,js,output) where it shows an example how you could send the data to the server using jQuery's $.ajax. 
It does it on *keydown* event however, and to save requests, I would suggest doing it on *blur*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use Ajax. If you want to "live update" it, use `input` event to listen when the `contenteditable` changes; or create a button if you want to save your value "when they're done".