# how to dynamically change bootstrap alert test using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
<div id="signUpError"></div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSignUpError(message) {
        document.getElementById('signUpError').innerHTML="<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+message+"</div>";    
    }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
$error="this is error"
```

How to call `showSignUpError($error)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to provide sufficient details explaining your problem so that others can understand and help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
showSignUpError(<?php echo $error; ?>);
```

Try that first, but it *might* be necessary to quote the text:

```
showSignUpError("<?php echo $error; ?>");
```

Note that this will only run once, on page load.

If you wish to call-out to the PHP code while interacting with user, then you should check out AJAX:

[AJAX request callback using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)

Comment: Missing some quotes around the `PHP` though, making it a JS variable rather than a string