# Change the value of a variable on click

Tags: jquery, html, countdown

I'm trying to change the value of a variable when a button is clicked and pass the new variable to another function using jQuery, but it isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var day;
    $('button#visual-live-time').on('click',function(){
        var day = $('#datetimepicker').val();
    });

    $('div.countdown').countdown(day, function(event){
        $(this).text(event.strftime('%D ημέρες %H ώρες %M λεπτά %S δευτερόλεπτα'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Ημερομηνία και ώρα έναρξης</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <input type="text" size="35" name="event-title" id="datetimepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="text" id="visual-live-time"></div>
<div class="countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the value over time, you will need to use a back-end server language like PHP.

Use PHP to store the value in a database, like MySQL, and then use PHP to get this value when you access teh Admin page.  Place the value into the HTML field, and use javascript (countdown plugin) to animate the countdown that the human Admin will see.

Here is an answer that may help with an overview of what you need to do:

[PHP - Secure member-only pages with a login system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734297/php-on-user-click-query-database-and-get-answer/34735490#34735490)

For more information about PHP, you can review these (free) videos on TheNewBoston:

https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=11

Answer (score 1):

Put your `var day;` outside the document ready. Because it is now only within the bounds of document ready function as below

```
var day;
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('button#visual-live-time').on('click',function(){
        day = $('#datetimepicker').val();
    });

    $('div.countdown').countdown(day, function(event){
        $(this).text(event.strftime('%D ημέρες %H ώρες %M λεπτά %S δευτερόλεπτα'));
    });
});
```

Comment: hey thanks the for code already tryed that but it still not working have a look https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=CTpizONmwb

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables named "day". Remove the"var" before the second and it'll be the same variable

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, still the problem remains

Comment: put your countdown function inside the click listener too

Comment: Already tryed that and its working but the countdown disappears when i reload the page. The counter is the final countdown plugin