# Can an Ajax function birth another Ajax function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a .live Ajax function (let's call this x) which executes onclick and connects to the database with a 
url: myphpvalues.php.

Inside this php I have added another Ajax .live function (let's call this y) to be output once the user clicks the first Ajax link.

Is this allowed?

Comment: Is there a law against it? No clue what you are asking? Maybe if you showed some basic code.

Comment: Please add your code segment.

Comment: `.live` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7, and was removed in 1.9. So unless you're using an old version of jQuery, you should use `.on()` instead`.

Comment: The AJAX callback function can execute any Javascript it wants. If it performs another AJAX call, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `.live` has nothing to do with AJAX. It allows us to trap a user event (click, hover, etc) on controls that do not yet exist in the DOM. If you are using a version of jQuery later than 1.7, then [`.live` has been replaced with `.on`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (essentially the same syntax). If a little foggy, [please read this.](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) *Basically, if you didn't use `.on()` the jQuery code would not bind to the clicked element because the element didn't exist when the binding was attempted.*

Also, if you are a little foggy on AJAX, [please review this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884323/how-to-use-ajax-to-get-data-from-db-and-display-on-page/34884926#34884926) before continuing.

Because AJAX allows a javascript routine to request/receive data from a back-end (PHP) file, there is no need to use AJAX within that back-end file -- it's already PHP *(or ASP.Net or whatever)* and can `include` (or whatever) routines from other PHP files.

However, if you are asking if you can return new javascript/jQuery code back to the originating HTML/js page, yes you can. You can send back any html/js/css code that you like.

And can this new code include another AJAX code block? Yes it can. Give it a try! You will probably need to use `.on()` again, though.