# PHP Output Variable Not Appearing

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am using an open source login repository from Github (https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal) to create a login system for my website. The login process seems to be successful and the new user registrations are populating to my MySQL database, but when I try to echo session variables like the username it is just coming up blank.

Here's a sample code that doesn't show up:

```
<p>Hey, <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>. You are logged in.</p>
```

and I have also tried this:

```
<p>Hey, <?php echo("{$_SESSION['user_name']}"); ?>. You are logged in.</p>
```

but to no avail.  You can also see how this problem works on the live site at http://www.geneticgolf.com/views/logged_in.php .

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure authentication is happening?  That's when the `$_SESSION` var is set.  have you tried `print_r($_SESSION);` to see if it has ANY data?

Comment: Have you started the session? `session_start()`..

Comment: That class seems like an overly odd way to handle authentication... but thats just an opinion.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - *says all, reveals all*.

Comment: The only question(s) I see here, are yours @Darren and Andrew Coder's ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that at the top of the same page that has this code:

```
<p>Hey, <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>. You are logged in.</p>
```

that you have (as the first instruction):

```
<?php
    session_start();
```

If you have that correct, then try this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo '<pre>'
    echo $_SESSION;
    echo '</pre>'
    die();
```

At the least, that will tell you what is in your $_SESSION variable.

This post might be helpful to you in trying to solve your problem:

[PHP - Secure member-only pages with a login system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734297/php-on-user-click-query-database-and-get-answer/34735490#34735490)