# Restrict access to private images

Tags: javascript, php, html, restrictions

As a photographer, I have my own website with a portfolio and such. I also have a log-in system for users, where I give them access to their own private images (it displays all images placed inside a specific folder - I do this manually for each user).

When a user logs in and sees his private images, he'll notice the URL says the following (when he downloads it/clicks it/etc): 
www.mywebsite.com/FOLDER_NAME/IMG_123.jpg

By simply doing a bit of guessing, he'll be able to find other users private images. Of course this is defeats the purpose of having private images on my website, so I have to find a way around that.

At the moment, the user can only see his private images if his user_email (unique) matches userRow:

```
if ($userRow['user_email'] == "email@hotmail.com")
```

I'm not so sure what to search for. Restrict access to images wasn't a successful search query for me.

What can I do? I guess an option would be to call the folders something random, such as:
"Charles661846Xkdfdsnf34590u". That will be hard to guess, but I'm not so sure about security (as in if there are other ways to get access to the root?).

I have taken a look at [Deny direct access to all .php files except index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php) but that is not what I want exactly.

What can I do in this case?

I've programmed my site in php,html and a bit javascript.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to restrict access to files only to a logged-in user, you should move all files from the web-root and put them in a place where you cannot access them directly through the web-server.

Then you serve the files after the user is authenticated through php. See for example the first example on the [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) page of the php manual.

So when a user logs in, you store for example the user ID in a session variable and on top of the file-serving script you check if the id is correct / allowed access to that specific file.

Answer (score 1):

Further to what Jeroen has said, you're on the right track in identifying that the folder name could be the weak point, and that it should be difficult/impossible to guess. There is no need to name folders after users; you can create a random 8, 12 or 16-char alphanumerical string and store that in the userRow as, perhaps, `$userRow['folder_name']`.

You can also put all user folders under a structure like `http://example.com/storage/A97LD34B2` and ensure that the `storage` folder has an `.htaccess` file with:

```
Options All -Indexes
```

That's all you need in that text-only file. *This, of course, assumes you have an Apache web server (by far the most common, especially for shared hosting accounts.)* This file would prevent Mr Snoopy from navigating to `http://example.com/storage` and seeing a list of files.

Here are two S.O. questions that outline how to construct a password-protected members-only system:

[Login into a website and get html from a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221946/login-into-a-website-and-get-html-from-a-page/36223830#36223830)

[PHP - Secure member-only pages with a login system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734297/php-secure-member-only-pages-with-a-login-system/34735490#34735490)

Note that each folder would contain an `index.php` file that would serve up files as jeroen described.