# how window location in javascript when localStorage but not reload page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

im using this code javascript with localStorage (something like session in php)

```
<script>
$(function(){
        var a = localStorage.getItem('login');
        if(a=="" || a==null){window.location.href = "dash-home.html";}
        else{window.location.href = "dash-chat.html";}
    }); 
</script>
```

but when location in dash-home.html, that page always refresh page (F5 repetitive)

Comment: When redirecting to dash-home, that means the user is logged in. If yes, then you need to set the `login` value in localStorage.

Comment: When you set `window.location.href`, the page will refresh.

Comment: im done with that, my ask 'when redirecting dash-home always refresh ?' @Tushar

Comment: Make sure to your 'script' is not available in your "dash-home.html" since it is your neutral ground.

Comment: so, what do i use ? @fauxserious

Comment: `a=="" || a == null` is redundant. `null == ""` is a true statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you understand that AJAX / PHP is the best solution.

But if you cannot use AJAX, you can use the `.load()` jQuery method to *simulate* AJAX. `.load()` will load the contents of another file into your document WHEN and WHERE you want.

Example:

```
if (condition == true){
    $('targetDIV').load('desired_page.html');
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

---

More information about AJAX:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17974843

---

**For your example:**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var a = localStorage.getItem('login');
        if(a=="" || a==null){$('#targetDIV').load("dash-home.html");}
        else{$('#targetDIV').load("dash-chat.html");}
    }); 
</script>

<body>
    <div id="targetDIV"> This is where the other pages will appear </div>
```

Comment: why not just `if (condition)` ?