# why I can't get the value when make a jquery/ajax call on link click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my website I have a  link where user id is store like this :

```
<p>by <a href="#" onclick="ofUser(<?php echo $uid; ?>, event);"><?php echo $store_name; ?> (<?php echo $no_pro_of_user; ?>)</a></p>
```

Here you can see variable `$uid`. This is the user id. So I want to make ajax call when I click on this link. It's should get the value of `$uid` to result page `ofUser.php`. But in result page (ofUser.php) it's showing :

**Undefined index: id**

Can you tell me how can I solve it ?

**Here is the JS offUser function**

```
function ofUser(id, event){
  id = $(id);
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData =  id;      
  $.ajax({
    url :  <?php echo "'ofUser.php'"; ?>,
    type : 'POST',
    xhr : function () {
      var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      return myXhr;
    },
    beforeSend : function () {
      $("#ofUser_message").val("Searching...");
    },
    success : function (data) {
      $("#danger").hide();
      $("#bydault_pagination").hide();
      $("#bydeafult_search").hide();
      $("#ofUser_message").html(data);                            
    },

    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });  
}
```

**offUser.php**

```
echo $uid = (int) $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Why `id = $(id);` ? Why are you making it jQuery object ?

Comment: you haver id = $(id).  If this is the 1st time you're declaring this variable, you should use:  var id = $(id) otherwise it will be undefined and could cause the error you're reporting.

Comment: oh mistake. I want to get the value of Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id = $(id);` will cast `id` to jQuery object which is not making any sense here. It will make `id` as `array`(`id=$(1) => [1]`)

Also note, your `data` being sent over server should be an object.

Try this:

```js
function ofUser(id, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ofUser.php',
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {
      var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      return myXhr;
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#ofUser_message").val("Searching...");
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#danger").hide();
      $("#bydault_pagination").hide();
      $("#bydeafult_search").hide();
      $("#ofUser_message").html(data);
    },

    data: {
      id: id
    },
    cache: false
  });
}
```

**Edit:** Remove `processData : true` as it will send data as `DOMDocument`

Comment: It's showing : Undefined index: id in on result page.

Comment: Yea. It's Working :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to pass  `id = id;` instead `id = $(id);` because $(id) means you are trying to get any DOM element values using jQuery, I hope it will work, also tell me that, what HTML is generated for your this code

```
<p>by <a href="#" onclick="ofUser(<?php echo $uid; ?>, event);"><?php echo $store_name; ?> (<?php echo $no_pro_of_user; ?>)</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, SIMPLIFY to make sure you are correctly passing the ID value. In your AJAX success function, ALERT the value you send back so you can immediately see what you received in PHP.

Try setting it up this way instead:

**html:**

```
<p>by <a id="uid_<?php echo $uid; ?>" href="#" ><?php echo $store_name; ?> (<?php echo $no_pro_of_user; ?>)</a></p>
```

**javascript:**

```
$('[id^=uid_]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = this.id.split('_')[1];
    $("#ofUser_message").val("Searching...");

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
         url : 'ofUser.php',
        data : id=formData,
        success : function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#danger").hide();
            $("#bydault_pagination").hide();
            $("#bydeafult_search").hide();
            $("#ofUser_message").html(data);                            
        }
    });


});
```

**ofUser.php**

```
$uid = $_POST['id']; //REMOVE the (int) for now, to verify what PHP is receiving - then add it back.
echo 'Received $uid';
```

Notes:

(1) Note that you misspelled ofUser.php and offUser.php (not sure which is correct - I went with ofUser.php)

(2) Try not to use inline javascript. jQuery is easiest to use when you break out the javascript from the HTML, as per above example.

(3) In above example, the jQuery selector **`starts with`** is used:

```
$('[id^=uid_]').click(function(event){
```

That code is fired by any element whose ID begins with `uid_`, as we configured the `<a>` tag's ID to appear. That makes it easy to see in your HTML.

(4) This line:

```
var formData = this.id.split('_')[1];
```

uses pure javascript to get the ID, because it's faster - and simpler to type. The code splits off the 2nd part of the ID, at the `_` char, resulting in just the ID number. That ID number is then assigned to the variable `formData`

(5) In the AJAX code block, make sure the url is spelled correctly:

```
url : 'ofUser.php',
```

Here are some other SIMPLE AJAX examples that might help. Don't just look at them - reproduce them on your server and play with them. They are simple, but you may learn a lot:

[AJAX request callback using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)

Answer (score 0):

When click over any hyperlink then start redirecting to provided URL. so you need to prevent its default action using below code inside your click event handler

```
event.preventDefault();
```