# Detect user click on an HTML table TD, and get value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to post some data when visitors click on a "td".

Here is the code:

```
<form method="post" name="randoms">
<tr><td value="1" name="somedata">Click me 1</td></tr>
<tr><td value="2" name="somedata">Click me 1</td></tr>
<tr><td value="3" name="somedata">Click me 1</td></tr>
<tr><td value="4" name="somedata">Click me 1</td></tr>
</form>
```

What I want here is that if a visitor clicks at "Click me 1" it post the form and then I'll be able to grab the somedata with PHP.

```
<?php
$somedata = $_POST["somedata"];
?>
```

I've tried to solve this, but I cannot find a way to do this, I'm pretty sure there are lots of way to do it.

I've tried this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(sub) {
document.forms[sub].submit();
}
</script>
```

and then I've tried to use:

```
<a HREF="#" onClick="submitForm('randoms')"> Somedata1 </a>
```

Comment: Can you include the code you have already tried?

Comment: `<td>` elements don't have a value attribute and you're missing the opening and closing table tags. Also, where's the JavaScript you tried?

Comment: Ive included the one ive tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned above,  your table is not formatted well,  add opening and closing tags

name your form withban id or class `<form id="myForm"... >`

use data attribute on td like

```
<td data-id="1" data-some-data="somename">
```

add 2 hidden input fieod in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myId" >
<input type="hidden" id="somedata" >
```

try something like

```
$( "#myForm td" ).click(function() {
  $('#myId").val($(this).data('id'));
  $('#somedata").val($(this).data('someData'));
  $( "#myForm" ).submit();
});
```

and of course et up a form action url.

if you really wanna be safe check if data attr.  exists like

```
if ($(this).data().hasOwnProperty( 'someData') )  { //do stuff }
```

ok if u wanna click specific td add a class to them like

```
<td class="clickable"......
```

an modif

```
 $( "#myForm td" ).click(function()
```

to

```
$( "td.clickable" ).click(function() {
```

Comment: sorry you dont need []  before .submit

Comment: yepp,  thanx.  im new here :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put a `value` attribute into a `td`, but you can use the `id` attribute to do something similar. Here is a full example that might help:

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['newdata']) ){
        $val = $_POST['newdata'];
        echo 'Received value: ' .$val;
        die();
    }else{

?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('td').click(function(){
            alert(this.id);
            var myTD = this.id.split('_')[1];
            var newFrm = '<form id="myNewForm"><input name="newdata" value="' +myTD+ '" /></form>';
            $('body').append(newFrm);
            $('#myNewForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    td{padding:3px 7px;border:1px solid #bbb;}
</style>
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr><td id="td_1">Click me 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="td_2">Click me 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="td_3">Click me 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="td_4">Click me 4</td></tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
    }
?>
```

---

If you would like to POST the data (and perhaps update a database) behind the scenes, use AJAX. See the simple examples in this post for how easy it is:

[AJAX request callback using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)

---

To answer your comment question: in order to restrict which TDs are `clickable`, add a class to the ones you want to make "clickable" and use that class to detect the user click:

```
<form method="post" name="randoms">
    <tr><td value="1">Cant click me 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td value="2" class="clickme">Click me 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td value="3" class="clickme">Click me 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td value="4">Cant click me 4</td></tr>
</form>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.clickme').click(function(){
            alert(this.id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

*You probably already know this, but for future readers:* Note the `.`, which means "class=". An `id` attribute is represented by a `#`. When you use a class name in the jQuery selector *`$('.clickme').click()`,* every element with that class is monitored. But IDs must be unique -- only one element per page can have that specific ID. If more than one element has the same ID, terrible things will happen: earthquakes, famine, tsunamis, unpredictable code results. Don't go there.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work only for those td like if i add a <tr><td>Chose opption</td></tr> over them and click it then nothing happens? cuz now everywhere theres a td that gets clicked it post :)

Answer (score 0):

Table data cells are not form controls. Use form controls.

```
<button type="submit" value="1" name="somedata"> Click me 1 </button>
```

No need for JS at all.

If you have tabular data (it doesn't look like you do) then you can put the button in a call, but note that a `<tr>` element cannot be a child element of a `<form>` element.

Answer (score 0):

As Quention said, table data cells are not form controls.
If you want to make use of AJAX and have the td's clickable you could do something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    tds.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // DO XHR Request
    });
</script>

<form>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="somename" />Click me 1</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="somename" />Click me 1</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="somename" />Click me 1</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="somename" />Click me 1</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```