# div does not reload the changed content even with 'load'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have been working on this for some time now. I have a php file that has a div which reads a directory and loads the files in the directory into a dropdown. When the user selects from the file the file gets selected and teh operation is performed. However, the file name does not disappear from the dropdown until the page is refreshed. I have tried '.load' and it doesn't work. As in, the content of the div does not get updated.

My code is as follows:
This is the PHP file:

```
<div id="mgA" class="form-group">
<label>Management Address:</label>
 <?php
   $path = "/licenses/ve/address/unused";
   clearstatcache();
  $files = array();
  $handle = opendir($path);
  echo '<select required id="mgmtAdd" class="form-control select2"      style="width: 100%;">';
  while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
 if (substr($file,0,1) != ".") {
 $files[]=$file;
  }
 echo "<option selected = 'selected' value='0'>Select</option>";
 natsort($files); //sorting
 foreach($files as $file){
 echo "<option value ='$file'>$file</option>";
 }
 echo '</select>';
   if (is_dir_empty($path)) {
    echo "Max no of hosts already created";
    }

function is_dir_empty($path) {
 if (!is_readable($path)) return NULL;
     return (count(scandir($path)) == 2);
  }
closedir($handle);?>
```

This is the button which on click the div should reload all the contents again:

```
   $( "#vServer").on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#mgA").load(virtualDialog);

    alert("refreshed");

    virtualDialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
```

Please let me know if anyone has any idea, any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: what is `virtualDialog`? does not make sense from your code since you are using it as a URL and as an element

Comment: Hi @epascarello                                                                                 virtualDialog is variable in which I have stored a jquery dialog box: virtualDialog = $( "#virtualServerForm" ).dialog                                      This is the id of the dialog box<div id="virtualServerForm" class="modal">

Comment: so that makes no sense with `load`

Comment: I am using .load as i think that's the only way to reload the div, it would be great if you could suggest a better method or let me know what I am doing wrong... @epascarello

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ excepts a URL to load data from the server.

Comment: yes, I agree. I am in the process of adding a url to it and editing my controller php file... will update if that works out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As epascarillo has pointed out, you are using `load()` incorrectly.  This may be more in line with what you wish to do *but I did not test (or even check very closely) your PHP code.*

I am also assuming that the div `#mgA` is the content of the jQueryUI dialog that you are opening with virtualDialog.

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$( "#vServer").on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
         url: 'ajax-reload.php',
        success: function(d){
            $("#mgA").html(d);
            virtualDialog.dialog( "open" );
        }
    });
});
```

**ajax-reload.php**

```
<?php
    $path = "/licenses/ve/address/unused";
    clearstatcache();
    $files = array();
    $handle = opendir($path);
    $out = '<select required id="mgmtAdd" class="form-control select2"      style="width: 100%;">';
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
        if (substr($file,0,1) != ".") {
            $files[]=$file;
        }
        $out .= "<option selected = 'selected' value='0'>Select</option>";
        natsort($files); //sorting
        foreach($files as $file){
            echo "<option value ='$file'>$file</option>";
        }
    } //<=== this brace was missing
    $out .= '</select>';
    if (is_dir_empty($path)) {
        $out = "Max no of hosts already created";
    }

    function is_dir_empty($path) {
        if (!is_readable($path)) return NULL;
        return (count(scandir($path)) == 2);
    }
    closedir($handle);
    echo $out;
?>
```

See these additional examples of simple AJAX -- sometimes it helps to see the really simple examples:

[AJAX request callback using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)

Comment: Hi @gibberish thank u for your reply! I am sure this will work, but i am using the codeigniter framework and the problem is that I am not able to understand where to write it as I have a separate php file for adding a VM in the views, and I have a controller php file too.