# Bootstrap Modal with editable data in php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I want to edit data by using modal with editable data.

```
$HTML='<script> var js_array = '.JSON_encode($result).';
        </script>';
        echo $HTML;
```

and in javascript

```
   var id=supplier_id;
                     $.ajax({
            url:"index.php/Supplier/edit",
            type:"POST",
            data:{ID:id},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
            .............??????????????..................
            alert(js_array['SupplierCode']);

            },  

            });
```

}

Now I have JSON object but i tried to access the objects individually but it is not working.

I have my data in the following format:

```
var js_array = {"SupplierCode":"52","SupplierName":"GANE","Address":"79\/9 UR ST","City":"TANJORE","State":"TN","Country":"IN","PinCode":"624531","ContactPerson":"GANI","MobileNumber":"8807892105","TelephoneNumber":null,"EmailID":"gani@fun.in","FaxNumber":null,"Website":"www.gani.in"};
```

Comment: $HTML='<script> var js_array = "' .JSON_encode($result). '";</script> -- the text must be quoted, so equals double-quote single-quote .PHP. single-quote double-quote semicolon

Comment: @gibberish Could you please make that comment into an answer question mark

Comment: @gibberish Still i could not get alert to get the objects . Is there any mistakes in ajax code? could you confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve everything for you, but the PHP must be:

```
$HTML = '<script> var js_array = "' .JSON_encode($result). '";</script>
```

JSON_encode creates text, and text must be quoted, so: *equals double-quote single-quote .PHP. single-quote double-quote semicolon*

---

And try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"a_different_php_file.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{ID:supplier_id},
    dataType: 'json', //this only affects data coming BACK from PHP
    cache: false,
    success: function(obama) {
        alert(obama);
    }
});
```

**a_different_php_file.php**

```
<?php
    $recd = $_POST['ID'];
    echo $recd;
```

Note that your PHP ajax processor file must be a secondary PHP file. You cannot process AJAX in a different section of the same PHP file that contains the javascript AJAX routine.

Resource:

[See the **this post** link in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)

Comment: Ya I tried your code, but still i couldn't get expected alert from ajax. So the ajax may be error.

Comment: @mul1103 See update (which has been further updated - F5 refresh pls.

Comment: First of all i have a table . I select a row , then click on  edit button appears the editable data modal. For that i am using JSON and already i posted the data now i want to get the selected rows data.

Comment: `alert(obama.SupplierCode);` -- that assumes that the data sent back from the PHP side is the JSON string displayed at the bottom of your question -- `alert('Name is: ' + obama.SupplierName);`

Comment: Hi i tried the above. It is not working. When i refer JSON tutorial the json objects within curly braces is single quoted not double quoted.

Comment: When i hide the dataType: json, it alerts the name is undefined. What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

That is a bad way of parsing JSON data.Try this:
In php:

```
JSON_encode($result);
```

In javascript:

```
 $.ajax({
        url:"index.php/Supplier/edit",
        type:"POST",
        data:{ID:id},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
        var parsed_json=JSON.parse(result)
        var supplierCode=parsed_json.SupplierCode;
        alert(supplierCode);
        },  

        });
```