# Refresh multiple divs with same ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have multiple `<div>` tags with the same ID. Based on day and time, I statements trigger to select relevant content.

I also monitor the Database constantly for new content and need to refresh the `<div>` to display the updated or new content.

I have tried something like `$("#myDiv").load('myPHPPage.php?);` with no success.

My PHP Code sample:

```
if($dayofweek == "Monday" && $timeofday >= "08:00:00" && $timeofday <= "11:59:59"){
//Monday morning timeslot
echo "<div id='slideshow'>";
$stmm= $conn->prepare("SELECT `Monday_Morning`
FROM `adsList`");
$stmm->execute();
while($resultst = $stmm-> fetch()){
$mondaymoringlist = $resultst["Monday_Morning"];
echo "<div class='slideshow'>";
//Display ad as an image
//<object data='/$adlist'></object>
echo "<object data='/$mondaymoringlist'></object>";
echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
}
//Monday Afternoon
if ($dayofweek == "Monday" && $timeofday >= "12:00:00" && $timeofday     <= "16:59:59"){
//Monday afternoon timeslot
echo "<div id='slideshow'>";
$stma= $conn->prepare("SELECT `Monday_Afternoon`
FROM `adsList`");
$stma->execute();
while($resultst = $stma-> fetch()){
$mondayafternoonlist = $resultst["Monday_Afternoon"];
echo "<div class='slideshow'>";
//Display ad as an image
//<object data='/$adlist'></object>
echo "<object data='/$mondayafternoonlist'></object>";
echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
}
//Monday Evening

else if ($dayofweek == "Monday" && $timeofday >= "17:00:00" && $timeofday <= "22:00:00"){
//Monday Evevening timeslot
echo "<div id='slideshow'>";
$stme= $conn->prepare("SELECT `Monday_Evening`
FROM `adsList`");
$stme->execute();
while($resultst = $stme-> fetch()){
$mondayeveninglist = $resultst["Monday_Evening"];
echo "<div class='slideshow'>";
//Display ad as an image
//<object data='/$adlist'></object>
echo "<object data='/$mondayeveninglist'></object>";
echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
}
//End of Monday
```

Every day of the week has similar timeslots.

I currently use `location.reload();` but it is no ideal as there is another `<div>` on the page which is also refreshing separately based on its own data check. With the other `<div>` I am able to do `$("#myDiv").load('myPHPPage.php?);` because it has a unique ID.

**AJAX**

```
function adshandler() {
var d = new Date();
var cache = d.getTime();
 $.getJSON("check_time.php?cache=" + cache, function(update) {
    if (update.count === true) {
        $("#slideshow").load();
    }
  }); 
 } 
 setInterval(adshandler, 600000);
```

Comment: Id should be unique in the DOM, you better work with classes

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between ID and className is that the className (aka class) can be associated with more than one element. By definition, *each ID on a page must be unique.*

When multiple elements have the same ID, changes will happen only to the first element (with that ID) on a page.

Change the IDs to classes.

For regular polling of databases, use a [recursive setTimeout](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/a-recursive-settimeout-pattern) and an [AJAX code block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843).

Comment: Thanks. Can I then use `$("#myDiv").load('myPHPPage.php?); ` to refresh the `<div>`  when new content is available. ?

Comment: 1) How are you monitoring your DB? *(How do you know when new content is available?)* 2) How many DIVs are named #myDiv? *(How many DIVs should be updated with new material)* 3) Please show your relevant HTML 4) Please show your repeating AJAX code 5) Please show relevant PHP, including (simplified) sample output

Comment: So `check_time.php` returns boolean -- what is this line intended to do (detailed): `$("#slideshow").load();` ?

Comment: `$("#slideshow").load();` is intended to refresh the `<div>` with `id` and `class` slideshow.