# Need from PHP code to create Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I need some help creating Ajax, which I am not familiar with.

This is my actual PHP code that works:

```
$channels = array("channel1","channel2");
$arrlength = count($channels);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {


$ch = curl_init("somemyapiurl".$channels[$x]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$kanal = curl_exec($ch);  
$kanal_decode= json_decode($kanal); 
$ch_name= $kanal_decode ? 'true' : 'false';
echo "<button type='button' id= '".$channels[$x]."' class='btn btn-success'>"$channels[$x]."</button>&nbsp";

echo "<script>
if($ch_name == false) {
document.getElementById('$channels[$x]').className='btn btn-danger';
}  </script>";}}
```

So what I do here is actually for every value in `$channels`, I am checking api and create button on page, with default class success.
If API returns value false , then with script I am changing button class.

Until now, I was doing refresh of page for some interval, but now I want to my page do this dynamically without refreshing it and I know I need ajax.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: So write the code that does just that. But please don't us ask to do your work for you.

Comment: i was trying but i am new with coding ,and as i say i dint "catch" Ajax that well..

Comment: @savke24 You should do some ajax tutorials first. Get to know jquery and it's pjax is a good start.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1):

The way AJAX works is you call out to a PHP file, it does some work, it uses PHP `echo` command to return data to the AJAX code block where it is received in the `success` function (or the `.done()` function) - and from there you now have the data returned by PHP in a variable. You can parse it (if a json object) and iterate through its elements to build HTML, or you can just directly inject the returned data (whether PHP returned HTML or just a couple of words or numbers).

[This post has some very simple AJAX examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843) to review / experiment with.