# Form Submission - No Refresh/Hide Div after submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

When I submit the form it redirects me back to the same page using this code

**PHP**

```
if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail; 
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message"; 

$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: index.html');
}
```

What I want it to do is stay on the same page without refreshing and then hide the div..

**HTML**

```
            <div class="footer">
            <div id="containerfooter">
                <form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php" class="NewsLetter" class="NL__field NL__email"> 
                <p>
                <label for='name'>Your Name:</label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="NL__field NL__email">
                </p>
                <p>
                <label for='email'>Email Address:</label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
                </p>
                <p>
                <label for='message'>Message:</label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="message">
                </p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
        $('form').submit(function(){
        $('#containerfooter').hide();  
    });
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Forms vs AJAX

Forms allow you to take user-entered data and send it to another PHP file for processing. However, when the form is submitted, navigation moves to the other PHP page (the one specified in the `action=""` attribute on the form tag:

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php" class="NewsLetter" class="NL__field NL__email">
```

In above tag, upon clicking submit button, the browser navigates to `contact-form-handler.php`

AJAX was invented to solve that, allowing you to send the data to the second PHP file, and (optionally) receive different data/html back ***without changing or refreshing the current page***

Here is an SO post with some very simple examples of AJAX. It is not difficult - just copy the examples to your server and make them work on your server. Play with them a bit. The fifteen minutes you spend doing that will save you ***hours.***

[AJAX request callback using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)

Note: In this day and age, it is almost never necessary to use FORMs. Everything can be done via AJAX - and it's so simple, why wouldn't you?

Note2: When using AJAX with `<form></form>` tags, you must use `e.preventDefault()` to keep the form tag from navigating you away from the current page (the form tag's default action):

```
$('myButton').submit(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    //the rest of your js code, including ajax code block
```