# PHP HTML Bootstrap - Using validator plugin with PHP in Bootstrap form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form that allows new users to be added to a database, but must this form must be 'authorised' with a valid code before being submitted. I have some PHP that works for this but the output is a crude tick or cross, indicating whether the code is valid or not. I want to instead make use of the [Bootstrap Validator plugin](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) to indicate whether the code is valid or not, however I'm not sure how to go about this. I am using the validator plugin on the form already, but it is currently only testing whether or not the field has been filled in, rather than using the PHP to test whether or not the code in the field is valid. If anyone could have a look it would be greatly appreciated.

Form.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Add New</title>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validator.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validator.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="section text-left">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                            <!-- Padding -->
                            <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:30px;">
                            </div>

                            <!-- Form begins -->
                            <form action="insert_preflight.php" method="post" data-toggle="validator" data-disable="false">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label " for="first_name">First Name</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" type="text" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label " for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" id="last_name" maxlength="40" name="last_name" type="text" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label " for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob" maxlength="10" type="date">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label " for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" type="email">
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="form-group has-feedback" id="auth_code_form">
                                    <label for="auth_code" class="control-label ">Authorisation Code</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" id="auth_code" name="auth_code" type="password" required>
                                    <!-- <span id="auth_code_result"></span> -->
                                    <span id="auth_code_result" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-info " name="submit" type="submit">Add</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var x_timer;
        $("#auth_code").keyup(function(e) {
            clearTimeout(x_timer);
            var auth_code = $(this).val();
            x_timer = setTimeout(function() {
                check_auth_code_ajax(auth_code);
            }, 1000);
        });

        function check_auth_code_ajax(auth_code) {
            $("#auth_code_result").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.post('check.php', {
                'auth_code': auth_code
            }, function(data) {
                $("#auth_code_result").html(data);
            });
        }
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Check.php:

```
<?php

// Connection
include 'pdo_config.php';
try {
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$auth_code = $_POST["auth_code"];  
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_instructors WHERE auth_code = :auth_code");
$stmt->bindParam(':auth_code', $auth_code);
$stmt->execute();

$exists = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if(($exists > 0)){
    die('<img src="exists.png" />');
}else{
    die('<img src="no_exists.png" />');
    }
}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a plugin to save yourself work, but it may take way longer to figure out the plugin and how to make it work for your situation than simply rolling your own. Scary as it seems right now, writing validation code is easy.

*(The place to bring a validation plugin into the picture is if you need additional fancy validation - really precise email address validation, for example catching `justme@fake.com` etc).*

The first thing to determine is how to start the validation. You can validate each field as the user moves away from it (see 2nd example). You can validate on click of a button (see 1st example), or you can validate at the moment a form is submitted:

```
$('myForm').submit(function(){
   //pseudo-code example
   var allOkay = true;
   for loop{
      if (field not valid) allOkay = false;
   }
   if ( !allOkay) return false; //return false: stop submit and return control to user
});
```

Here is an example of a roll-your-own validation:

```js
var chkFld, arrAll = {'One':'f1','Two':'f2','Three':'f3','Four':'f4'};

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    var errMsg='', badFlds='', firstBad='';
    for(var key in arrAll){
        chkFld = '#'+arrAll[key];
        $(chkFld).removeClass('error');
        if ($(chkFld).val() ==''){
            $(chkFld).addClass('error');
            //alert('Please complete field ' + arrAll[key] );
            errMsg += '*' + key + '\n';
            if (firstBad=='') firstBad=chkFld;
        }
    }
    if (errMsg != '') {
        alert(errMsg);
        $(firstBad).focus();
    }
}); //END mybutt.click
```

```css
p{width:250px;text-align:right;}
.error{border:1px solid red;background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>One: <input type="text" id="f1"></p>
<p>Two: <input type="text" id="f2"></p>
<p>Three: <input type="text" id="f3"></p>
<p>Four: <input type="text" id="f4"></p>
<br />
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Go" />
```

To validate from the PHP, just set one of the fields to validate using AJAX. That is, perhaps on `blur()` (user leaving the field) trigger an ajax lookup of the data and either do nothing (good data) or return to the field with an error condition (invalid data)

Example:

```js
var chkFld, arrAll = {'One':'f1','Two':'f2','Four':'f4'};

//Field 3 validation only
$('#f3').blur(function(){
    var f3 = this.value;
   alert('You typed: ' + f3);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
     url: 'ajax/my_php_validator_file.php',
    data: 'f3=' + f3,
    success: function(recd){
      if (recd!='ok'){
        $('#f3').addClass('error').focus();
      }
    }
  });
});

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    var errMsg='', badFlds='', firstBad='';
    for(var key in arrAll){
        chkFld = '#'+arrAll[key];
        $(chkFld).removeClass('error');
        if ($(chkFld).val() ==''){
            $(chkFld).addClass('error');
            //alert('Please complete field ' + arrAll[key] );
            errMsg += '*' + key + '\n';
            if (firstBad=='') firstBad=chkFld;
        }
    }
    if (errMsg != '') {
        alert(errMsg);
        $(firstBad).focus();
    }
    $('#myForm').submit(); //or whatever
}); //END mybutt.click
```

```css
p{width:250px;text-align:right;}
.error{border:1px solid red;background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>One: <input type="text" id="f1"></p>
<p>Two: <input type="text" id="f2"></p>
<p>Three*: <input type="text" id="f3"></p>
<p>Four: <input type="text" id="f4"></p>
<br />
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Go" />
```

---

Here are some more simple AJAX examples to help you get the hang of it - don't just read them, reproduce them on your server and change some values. The 15 mins you spend will save you hours.

[AJAX request callback using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into making my own validation.