# PHP/MySQL: Deleting data from DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-delete

This is a little more complicated than the title may lead you to believe. I have a function that queries my DB as soon as a user enters the page. The query then returns the `id` and `note_name` (these are the names in the columns in my DB). I can get the notes to display just fine, where I'm having trouble is deleting them. I am very confused on how to dynamically tell the server which note is currently being selected.

Let me know if I have supplied enough information to solve this problem, I am removing unnecessary code to save space. All code is in the same `.php` script.

## notes.php

#### select_notes() function

```
// query DB for pre-existing notes
function select_notes() {
  include('includes/connection.php');
  
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  // make READ query to the db and return the results
  $query  = "SELECT `id`, `note_name` FROM `notes` WHERE `username`='$username'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // create empty array for future use
    $note_id   = [];
    $note_name = [];
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      // push all the data from $row into $note_name array
      array_push($note_id, $row['id']);
      array_push($note_name, $row['note_name']);
    }
    
    // close connection and return array containing note details from DB
    mysqli_close($conn);
    
    return [ $note_id, $note_name ];
  } else {
    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo '<p>No notes available</p>';
  }
}
```

#### Where `select_notes()` is being called in the HTML

```
<div class="saved-notes col-10 offset-1 col-md-4 offset-md-0">
          <header class="text-center">
            <h2>Saved Notes</h2>
          </header>
          <div class="pt-2">
            <form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" class="form-inline px-1" method="POST">
              <input class="form-control mb-1 mr-1" name="note_name" type="text">
              <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="create_note" type="submit" value="Save">
            </form>
            
            <?php
            
              if ($_POST['create_note']) {
                insert_note();
              }
              
              list($note_id, $note_name) = select_notes();
              
              foreach (select_notes() as $note) {
                foreach ($note as $value) {
                  echo '
                        <form action="notes.php" class="single-note-form" method="POST">
                          <button name="edit_note" type="submit">'.$value.'</button>
                          <button class="text-danger" name="delete_note" type="submit">&times;</button>
                        </form>
                  ';
                }
              }
              
            ?>
            
          </div>
        </div><!-- col -->
```

Comment: You have SQL injection in your code read this to prevent it.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: *"Let me know if I have supplied enough information to solve this problem"* - Actually, no. You left out the DELETE statement, where's that?

Comment: The DELETE statement has not been written in its entirety yet. I'm still working out how to let the DB know which `ID` to look for before attempting to waste time writing, deleting, and re-writing functions. 
    `function delete_note() {
      include('includes/connection.php');
      
      $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Delete form, you must embed the id of the note, you have selected in the query

```
<form action="notes.php" class="single-note-form" method="POST">
    <button name="edit_note" type="submit">'.$value.'</button>
    <button class="text-danger" name="delete_note" type="submit">&times;</button>
    //include a hidden field containing the records ID
    <input type="hidden" name="note_id" value="?" />
</form>
```

You will find the structure of you return array to be to limiting. Currently you have 2 arrays one with the note text ( I presume ) and one with the note ids.  I would combine this into a single row like this ( inside select_notes):

```
 $notes = [];
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $notes[] = ['id' => $row['id'], 'note_name' => $row['note_name']];
 }
 return $notes;
```

This way you will have a multi-dimension array, much like what the database returns, Then in your HTML:

```
foreach (select_notes() as $note) {
   echo '
<form action="notes.php" class="single-note-form" method="POST">
    <button name="edit_note" type="submit">'.$note['note_name'].'</button>
    <button class="text-danger" name="delete_note" type="submit">&times;</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="note_id" value="'.$note['id'].'" />
</form>';
}
```

Or some other way of getting `note_id` into the form.

If you need a list of the ids, it's very simple to pull it out of the multi-dimensional array using `$ids = array_column($notes, 'id')`, so you lose nothing by using a combined structure.  And in fact it makes the code, cleaner, shorter and more concise.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

But anyway, once it's embedded in the form, it becomes simple as it's passed with the post request. Then it's just a matter of `$_POST['note_id']` when you do the delete.

You should also use prepared statements in your query, even if it's session data and you think it's clean. Who knows what will change down the line and you may introduce a way for that value to be modified by a user, then it's open season.  SQL Injection prevention should always be done.  It takes very little effort to do and then you have piece of mind knowing your code is good.

One last thing:

```
$query  = "SELECT `id`, `note_name` FROM `notes` WHERE `username`='$username'";
```

I would say using the `username` is probably going to cause you grief at some point.  This should really use the `id` from the user table.  Now your usernames may be unique, but from a purely performance standpoint, using a numeric index is way faster then strings.  And, well it just sort of bugs me...

Comment: `You should also use prepared statements in your query` Thanks for this, I'm going to look more into preventing attacks as I become more experienced in PHP. `You will find the structure of you return array to be to limiting, so you will have to modify this` Well how would you suggest I go about creating that? If I could just tell my script to add one index of `id` then add one index of `note_name` and just keep doing that then this would have been solved already. Is there even a way to create that?

Comment: Updated!  That should be good, sorry if there are any syntax errors.  Or if I get any variables out of wack, in a bit of a hurry, have to run....

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from your question is that hte user logs in, and is sent to this new page, where PHP code sends back one or more notes associated with their username.

You display these notes on the page, but you want to know how to delete a note.

PHP runs once, then stops. It leaves off with the note(s) displayed on the page. Now, you need a way to (1) trap the user interaction (clicking on a note) and (2) send instruction to delete the note from the database.

A great way to do this is to use javascript/jQuery to trap the user click event, and (2) AJAX to send/receive data to/from another PHP file on the server (not to worry, much simpler than it sounds). The PHP file will receive the information and run a MySQL instruction to delete the appropriate note.

Here are some simple AJAX examples so you have an idea how it works.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17974843/1447509

Basically, your code will look something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.user-note', function(){
  var tmp = $(this).attr('id'); //assuming the id contains the note_id and you can isolate that, perhaps with .split()
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
     url: 'name_of_php_file_on_your_server.php',
    data: 'note_id=' +tmp+ '&what2do=delete'
  }).done(function(d){
    alert(d); //displays whatever the above PHP file echo's back to javascript
  });
});
```